# POST запрос для получения токена инстаграм с помощью retrofit

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit

нужно отправить POST запрос по адресу: 
curl -X POST \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token \
-F app_id=APP-ID \
-F app_secret=APP-SECRET \
-F grant_type=authorization_code \
-F redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI \
-F code=CODE
Возвращается ошибка 400 Invalid platform app. Client id правильный.
Подскажите правильно ли выполняют вообще POST запрос

```
public class CallResult {
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    public String access_token;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    public String user_id;
}

public interface Server {
    @POST("access_token")
    Call<CallResult> addToken(@Body Post names);
}

private void GetToken(String token){
    String user_info = getResources().getString(R.string.get_user_info_url);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(user_info) // Адрес сервера
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Post output = new Post();
    output.client_id = app_id;
    output.client_secret = app_secret;
    output.grant_type = grant_type;
    output.redirect_uri = redirect_uri;
    output.code = token;

    Server service = retrofit.create(Server.class);
    Call<CallResult> call = service.addToken(output);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<CallResult>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CallResult> call, Response<CallResult> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                CallResult repos = response.body();
                Log.e("CHECK", String.valueOf(repos));
            } else {
                Log.e("ERROR SERVER", String.valueOf(response.body()));
                Log.e("ERROR SERVER", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                Log.e("ERROR SERVER", String.valueOf(response.raw()));
                try {
                    Log.e("ERROR SERVER", response.errorBody().string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CallResult> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "GetToken: OnFailure");
        }
    });
}

private class Post{
    @SerializedName("client_id")
    String client_id;
    @SerializedName("client_secret")
    String client_secret;
    @SerializedName("grant_type")
    String grant_type;
    @SerializedName("redirect_uri")
    String redirect_uri;
    @SerializedName("code")
    String code;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не смог открыть вашу ссылку, но если я верно понял из

```
-F app_id=APP-ID \
-F app_secret=APP-SECRET \
-F grant_type=authorization_code \
-F redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI \
-F code=CODE
```

То вы неверно указали в аннотации `@SerializedName` поля. 
У вас должно быть так:

```
private class Post{
    @SerializedName("app_id")
    String client_id;
    @SerializedName("app_secret")
    String client_secret;
    @SerializedName("grant_type")
    String grant_type;
    @SerializedName("redirect_uri")
    String redirect_uri;
    @SerializedName("code")
    String code;
}
```

Попробуйте передвать параметры через body и в x-www-form-urlencoded как на скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все равно ошибка.

Comment: Все та же ошибка?

Comment: curl -X POST \ https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token \ -F client_id={app-id} \ -F client_secret={app-secret} \ -F grant_type=authorization_code \ -F redirect_uri={redirect-uri} \ -F code={code} вот это запрос с официальной документации

Comment: Да, ошибка та-же, я искал суть ошибки в том что у меня не тот app_id указан, но до этого я отправляю другой запрос и он проходит с этим id

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Попробуйте этот способ

Comment: Спасибо больше. Неделю потратил на один запрос

Comment: Рад был помочь=)